# application level db constraint forwarding: How to with JDBC and Spring automagically

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc, spring-validator

I would like to be able to essentially introspect the details of a schema all of my entities are bound to, and pull that forward to the application layer for validation so I don't submit data (and thus waste resources) to a db that will ultimately be rejected.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    Baz varchar(5) NOT NULL
);

@Entity
public class Foo {
   @Id
   public Long id;

   public String baz;

}


@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, Long> {}

Foo f = new Foo();
f.id = 1;
f.baz = "123456";

@Autowired 
FooRespository fooRepo;
fooRepo.save(f); // fails BEFORE going to DB with constrain violation.
```

I can clearly see I can implement this myself, but I am assuming somewhere out there in the great world is a bean/validator that will do this job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid a design that duplicates the rules laid down by your schema.  Your program would have to effectively reverse engineer the database every time it started to validate that it knows the constraints.  Additionally, if you have a clustered or distributed system a different program might insert a row that creates a constraint violation and your program would still have to deal with that error.

I'd encourage you to either (a) not worry about something that should not happen very frequently or (b) rethink your design if you're going to intentionally be breaking the schema often.

Having said that, the javax.validation.constraints package exists and can help you validate upfront that an object looks good.  But you'll be duplicating effort between, for example, the @NotNull annotation of javax.validation.constraints and your database schema.  Place the business rules in one place to minimize the amount of maintenance you'll need to do.

Comment: I use javax.validation already. If I place them business rules in the DB (one place) then I am merely forwarding (not duplicating) the rule. Duplicating would be having @NotNull on the entity field and NOT NULL on the column. If the constraint in the DB gets dropped the application could be unduly restrictive.